# Prepare numpy array -- similar to broadcasting

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have an m-dimensional matrix `M` and an array `N` of length `n`.

The shape of `M` is (a,b,n,e,f), meaning that on a particular axis (here, 2) the dimensionality of `M` agrees with that of `N`.

If I want to multiply them, in this particular case, I would do:

```
M * N[None, None, :, None, None]
```

How can I generalize this concept, to cases where the shape of `M` differs, and the axis may be a different one? I'm sure there must be a convenient function to extend array `N` accordingly, but I can't find anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll ilustrate several ways

```
In [29]: a,b,n,e,f = 2,3,4,5,6
In [30]: M=np.ones((a,b,n,e,f)); N=np.arange(n)
```

`N` can be expanded with `None`; only the trailing ones are required; leading ones are implicit

```
In [31]: (M*N[:,None,None]).shape
Out[31]: (2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

We could make a indexing tuple with something like:

```
In [32]: idx = [None]*M.ndim;idx
Out[32]: [None, None, None, None, None]    
In [33]: idx[2]=slice(None)

In [34]: (M*N[tuple(idx)]).shape
Out[34]: (2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

Or we could reshape `N`, adding the needed trailing size 1 dimensions:

```
In [35]: shp = [1]*M.ndim; shp[2]=N.shape[0]
In [36]: (M*N.reshape(shp)).shape
Out[36]: (2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

Or use `expand_dims`, which uses that `reshape` under the covers.  get the (1,2) from the `ndim` and desired insert dimension

```
In [37]: N1=np.expand_dims(N,(1,2)); N1.shape
Out[37]: (4, 1, 1)    
In [38]: (M*N1).shape
Out[38]: (2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```